# Ruby - extracting the unique values per key from an array of hashes

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

From a hash like the below one, need to extract the unique values per key

```
array_of_hashes = [ {'a' => 1, 'b' => 2 , 'c' => 3} , 
                    {'a' => 4, 'b' => 5 , 'c' => 3}, 
                    {'a' => 6, 'b' => 5 , 'c' => 3} ]
```

Need to extract the unique values per key in an array

unique values for 'a' should give

```
[1,4,6]
```

unique values for 'b' should give

```
[2,5]
```

unique values for 'c' should give

```
[3]
```

Thoughts ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use [`Array#uniq`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html#method-i-uniq):

```
array_of_hashes = [ {'a' => 1, 'b' => 2 , 'c' => 3} , 
                    {'a' => 4, 'b' => 5 , 'c' => 3}, 
                    {'a' => 6, 'b' => 5 , 'c' => 3} ]

array_of_hashes.map { |h| h['a'] }.uniq    # => [1, 4, 6]
array_of_hashes.map { |h| h['b'] }.uniq    # => [2, 5]
array_of_hashes.map { |h| h['c'] }.uniq    # => [3]
```

Comment: `|h|` is a block parameter.

Answer (score 0):

This is more generic:

```ruby
options = {}
distinct_keys = array_of_hashes.map(&:keys).flatten.uniq
distinct_keys.each do |k|
  options[k] = array_of_hashes.map {|o| o[k]}.uniq
end
```